# How can I restrict access of content to paid users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have working on wordpress based website, where I want to keep certain sections (pages/posts) open to all kind of users (free+paid), while some sections available to only those users who have paid. Is there any plugin available or do I need to work on code part. How can I do this. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The reason you've been given a -2 on your question is that this is not a programming question.

You need a paid service for that kind of functionality or program that out from scratch by yourself. There are plenty of plugins that do that for you. Or perhaps your can find some "free" plugin to do that (Not recommended).

I've used [wishlist](http://wishlistproducts.com/) before and it works great. Lots of setting to deal with though.